# Android Bottom App Bar with FAB curve position

Tags: android, performance, android-actionbar, floating-action-button

Is it possible to change the FAB cradle curve position from bottom curve to top curve?

As I saw in the official Material Design documentation are all bottom curve.

Thank you.

[image]